# When I opened the searched item, it is opening the first item of ListView not the searched one. Even if search and find the items successfuly

Tags: android, firebase, listview, searchview, baseadapter

When I opened the searched item, it is opening the first item of ListView not the searched one. Even if search and find the items successfuly.

I configure the adapter with "implements Filterable" and enable Listview with ".setTextFilterEnabled(true)", but doesn´t work.

I saw that I must  implement "public Filter getFilter()" but I have no idea how can I do that.

When I type some words in EditText, like "cel" or "12" the filter goes in action, but the result is always the same: The first two items in Listview, no matter what is into the Listview (the content of listview is random).

Below a snippet of my Activity:

```
public class MusicActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener  {
private boolean checkPermission = false;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ListView listView;
List<String> songsNameList;
List<String> songsUrlList;
List<String> songsArtistList;
List<String> songsDurationList;
ListAdapter adapter;
JcPlayerView jcPlayerView;
List<JcAudio> jcAudios;
List<String> thumbnail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_music);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    listView = findViewById(R.id.songsList);
    songsNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    songsUrlList = new ArrayList<>();
    songsArtistList = new ArrayList<>();
    songsDurationList = new ArrayList<>();
    jcAudios = new ArrayList<>();
    thumbnail = new ArrayList<>();
    jcPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.jcplayer);
    retrieveSongs();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {




            jcPlayerView.playAudio(jcAudios.get(i));
            jcPlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            jcPlayerView.createNotification();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


}

// RETRIEVING THE SONGS FROM THE SERVER
public void retrieveSongs() {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Songs");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Song song = ds.getValue(Song.class);
                songsNameList.add(song.getSongName());
                songsUrlList.add(song.getSongUrl());
                songsArtistList.add(song.getSongArtist());
                songsDurationList.add(song.getSongDuration());
                thumbnail.add(song.getImageUrl());

                jcAudios.add(JcAudio.createFromURL(song.getSongName(), song.getSongUrl()));
            }
            adapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), songsNameList, thumbnail, songsArtistList, songsDurationList);
            jcPlayerView.initPlaylist(jcAudios, null);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MusicActivity.this, "FAILED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}






/*@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.app_menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.searchmenu:
            startActivity(new Intent(MusicActivity.this,Search.class));
            break;


        case R.id.requestmenu:

            startActivity(new Intent(MusicActivity.this,UploadSongActivity.class));
            break;

        case R.id.sharemenu:




            break;

    }

    return true;
}*/






// Filter Class






// METHOD TO HANDEL RUNTIME PERMISSIONS
private boolean validatePermissions(){
    Dexter.withContext(getApplicationContext())
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                    checkPermission = true;
                }
                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                    checkPermission = false;
                }
                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                    permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
    return checkPermission;

}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Query Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
        adapter.filter("");
        listView.clearTextFilter();
    }else{
        String texto = newText;
        adapter.filter(newText);
    }
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmenu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search Catholic songs");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setIconified(false);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.search) {
        return true;
    }

    else if(id == R.id.Rate){
        /*if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //log.d("TAG", "The intersitial wasn't loaded yet.");
        }*/
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getString(R.string.packegname)));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (id ==R.id.sharemenu){

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "Hey ! check out this  music service that gives you access to Hundreds  of catholic  songs. through Catholic app at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(sendIntent);


    }
    else  if(id == R.id.uploadItem){

        if (validatePermissions()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,UploadSongActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and below my CustomAdapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

List<String> songNames;
List<String> thumbnails;
List<String> songArtist;
List<String> songDuration;
Context context;
private List<String> copyList;
private int searchedItem = -1;
private ArrayList<Song> arraylist;



public ListAdapter(Context context, List<String> songNames, List<String> thumbnails, List<String> songArtist, List<String> songDuration) {
    this.context = context;
    this.songNames = songNames;
    this.thumbnails = thumbnails;
    this.songArtist = songArtist;
    this.songDuration = songDuration;
    copyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    copyList.addAll(songNames);


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return songNames.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return songNames.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@SuppressLint({"InflateParams", "ViewHolder"})
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.songs_list_layout, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }



    Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
            .cornerRadiusDp(15)
            .build();

    Picasso.get().load(thumbnails.get(i)).transform(transformation).into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
    viewHolder.songName.setText(songNames.get(i));
    viewHolder.artistName.setText(songArtist.get(i));
    viewHolder.songDuration.setText(songDuration.get(i));
    return view;
}

public void filter(String queryText)

{

    songNames.clear();

    if(queryText.isEmpty())
    {
        songNames.addAll(copyList);
    }
    else
    {

        for(String name: copyList)
        {
            if(name.toLowerCase().contains(queryText.toLowerCase()))
            {
                songNames.add(name);
            }
        }

    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}





private static class ViewHolder{
   TextView songName;
    TextView artistName;
    TextView songDuration;
   ImageView thumbnail;
   CardView cardView;
   ImageView currentlyPlaying;

    ViewHolder(View view){
        songName = view.findViewById(R.id.songName);
        thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.songThumbnail);
        artistName = view.findViewById(R.id.artistName);
        songDuration = view.findViewById(R.id.songDuration);
        cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        currentlyPlaying = view.findViewById(R.id.currentlyPlaying);
    }
}
```

What is missing?

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improved your adapter, didn't test it but it should work... I think it's easier to forward the Song list than the lists for each field separately... You have the original list for filtering and filteredList for adapter views...

**EDITED: You have to implement Filterable, sorry i didnt see this...**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<Song> songlist;
    private final List<Song> filteredList;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Song> songlist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.songlist = songlist;
        filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        filteredList.addAll(songlist);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return filteredList.get(i); // return Song item
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;  //TODO change this to return song id
    }

    @SuppressLint({"InflateParams", "ViewHolder"})
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.songs_list_layout, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
                .cornerRadiusDp(15)
                .build();

        Song song = filteredList.get(i);

        Picasso.get().load(song.getImageUrl()).transform(transformation).into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
        viewHolder.songName.setText(song.getSongName());
        viewHolder.artistName.setText(song.getSongArtist());
        viewHolder.songDuration.setText(song.getSongDuration());
        return view;
    }

    
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering (CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (songlist != null && constraint != null) {
                filteredList.clear();
                List<Song> newValues = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Song song: songlist) {
                    if(constraint.length() == 0) {
                        newValues.add(song); //TODO change this if you want empty list
                    }else{
                        if(song.getSongName.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))  {
                            newValues.add(song);
                        }
                    }
                }
                filteredList.addAll(newValues);
                //filteredList = newValues;
                results.count = newValues.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults (CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
}



    private static class ViewHolder{
        TextView songName;
        TextView artistName;
        TextView songDuration;
        ImageView thumbnail;
        CardView cardView;
        ImageView currentlyPlaying;

        ViewHolder(View view){
            songName = view.findViewById(R.id.songName);
            thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.songThumbnail);
            artistName = view.findViewById(R.id.artistName);
            songDuration = view.findViewById(R.id.songDuration);
            cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            currentlyPlaying = view.findViewById(R.id.currentlyPlaying);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public void retrieveSongs() {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Songs");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                List<Song> songsList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Song song = ds.getValue(Song.class);
                    songsList.add(song);
                    jcAudios.add(JcAudio.createFromURL(song.getSongName(), song.getSongUrl()));
                }
                adapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), songsList);
                jcPlayerView.initPlaylist(jcAudios, null);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MusicActivity.this, "FAILED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Also its better to create one instance of adapter and swapData in retrieveSongs...

EDITED: Try something like this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Song song = (Song)adapter.getItem(i)
            jcPlayerView.playAudio(JcAudio.createFromURL(song.getSongName(), song.getSongUrl()));
            jcPlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            jcPlayerView.createNotification();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nothing is  changed sir ,  I  tried those step but not working, it gives me wrong result after to click my  searched item

Comment: My answer is related to filter not to clickListener... for click listener you have to set url to song object... when you click on item you will getItem song from list and take url from song object... (without jcAudios list)

Comment: This is my preferred question (onClickListener) what to do? , I tried my best , but I'm not good in this, plz help me

Comment: In OnItemClickListener you have a Song object and there is no need jcAudios lis, you can create url like JcAudio.createFromURL(song.getSongName(), song.getSongUrl()). Check Edited 2

Comment: This is was my preferred solution, very clean and efficient.Wow - I am impressed. This was the solution I am looking for!! Many thanks. It helps also to improve my understanding  to create one instance of adapter and swapData in retrieveSongs. Have a nice day

Comment: I guess you removed all these lists and you only use a list of songs as I suggested to you...

Comment: yes I did , it worked sir , thank you so much

Comment: Also you have to adjust jcPlayerView.initPlaylist(jcAudios, null) for this